# How to add toggle switch button to .net WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, togglebutton

I am working on a .NET WPF project using Visual Studio 2022. I want to add a toggle switch button to my app. I searched about this and none of the solutions looked proper with my app. How can it be done without adding external libraries. Is it possible? If not, what could be the best option to handle this?

I want something like this:
[image: Something like this]

Comment: You either add an external library(i can recommand MahApps cause their toggle switch looks exactly like you want) OR you can override CheckBox ControlTemplate to match your needs. This is not always easy if you want something like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also suggest mahapps metro.  You could grab the markup out the source.

Maybe it's this markup here.

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Themes/ToggleSwitch.xaml

I have a similar template for a checkbox. You could adapt or maybe you like the look anyhow. It's a bit quick and dirty.

The ellipse is animated left or right when you click

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="fillBrush">LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="borderBrush">Gray</SolidColorBrush>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid  Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                           Height="18"  
                           >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="34" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid  x:Name="markGrid" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="16" x:Name="moveEllipse"
                                       >
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="16" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" 
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                       Name="line"
                                       StrokeThickness=".8"
                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Margin="1,4,1,4"
                                 >
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Ellipse Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     StrokeThickness=".8"
                                     Name="spot"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     >
                                <Ellipse.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="CadetBlue"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Ellipse.Style>
                            </Ellipse>

                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="line" Value="DarkGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="spot" Value="DarkGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"  Value=".5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="line" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="spot" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="line" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="spot" Value="SkyBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="spot" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="line" Value="lightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And of course the colours are very easily changed.

Looks like this

[image]

or this

[image]

Line to the left is edge of window

Comment: With a little edit, this will be enough for me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways - you can override the ControlTemplate of CheckBox or ToggleButton, or you can create a UserControl.
Below is small example/idea which you can customize to don't have the hardcoded values.

In adjusted solution I just put two invisible ToggleButtons, which listen for click:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border x:Name="switch" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Height="20" Width="40" Padding="1" >
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
                
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <ToggleButton Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Name="tbLeft"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tbRight}" />

            <ToggleButton Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Name="tbRight"
                            IsChecked="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=switch}"/>

            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Ellipse Height="14" Width="14" Name="EL">
                    <Ellipse.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="19"/> <!-- 40-14-7 -->
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>

                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Ellipse.Style>
                </Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ToggleButton Content="Test it" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=switch}" Margin="2" Width="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But this example is done by using a seperate button. Is it possible to make switch clickable directly?